# Class ..Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony

I'm getting this error when I try to clear the cache (for example):

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping \MappingException]   Class
>   Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super
>   class.

This is User.php:

```
<?php
// src/Aib/PlatformBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

And this is the place where User.php is stored:

> javier@javier:~/programacion/aib/src/Aib/PlatformBundle/Entity$ ls
>   User.php  UserRepository.php

This is the AppKernel.php:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Aib\PlatformBundle\AibPlatformBundle(),
        ...
    );
```

sf 2.0.4

Comment: Do you have entity mappings set to autoload in your app/config.yml?

Comment: Why not answer Problematic's question?

Comment: InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"

I encounter such an exception with symfony 2.1-BETA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same experience with my implementation of the FOS UserBundle and found I was able to resolve the issue by removing the MyBundle\Resources\config\doctrine folder.

I dont fully understand the cause (newbie) but think the issue is a result of having database content built in bother directions, ie from doctrine entities and by reverse engineering some tables.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I was missing `* @ORM\Entity` in my class definition.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="listtype")
 */
class ListType
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be the app/config/config.yml

It needed the defintion of the default bundle as below NameBundle, then it worked fine

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          NameBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was solved by changing my servers cache from **eAccelerator** to **APC**.
Apparently eAccelerator strips all the comments from files which breaks your annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but this was because I wasn't including the Sonata Application:

try this:

add a line to your AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = array(
...
new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inherited from mapped class, you can add @ORM\SuperMappedClass in entity's annotation.
You can read most information in [this article](http://www.baptiste-donaux.fr/mappingexception-class-y-sub-class-of-x-is-not-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class/).